# change dateformat in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
set dateformat dmy
select isdate('31/1/2012')
```

I thought by going into **Change the format of numbers, dates, and times** in Windows Control Panel that I wouldn't have to **SET DATEFORMAT DMY** in sql?

So I made the change, omitted the set statment, and the isdate is still failing, what am I missing?

Comment: Why would windows UI settings define database settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use `TRY_PARSE` and specify a culture (e.g. `en-gb`). You can read about `TRY_PARSE` here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(v=sql.110).aspx

Much safer, of course, to use an unambiguous date format in the first place, and avoid all the culture nonsense. You can have the application convert user entry before it ever sees the database, or just avoid string input altogether - with a calendar control or drop downs you can dictate a safe format like `YYYYMMDD` and not have to worry about regional, language or dateformat settings - never mind trusting that all users are entering `d/m/y` vs. `m/d/y`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate(),111)
```

Here `111` is the date format. You can change it to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server usually runs under the `System` user account or `NETWORKSERVICE`. These take the regional settings at install time.

Thus, to change the regional settings of SQL Server you have to change the regional settings of the user account used by the sql server service.

You can change this by following the steps explained in [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Apply-regional-and-language-settings-to-reserved-accounts)

(I never tested this, but theoretical it should work.)

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Will this change be documented such that if the service account is later changed to a different user the same changes will occur? I don't think you should rely on user account settings for parsing strings within SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

SQL handles datetime in database regardless the server settings.
If you have a string in any format that looks like a datetime and you want to convert it you can use CAST() or CONVERT() todo this. But you always have to.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

A good info is also http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

In your case

```
select isdate('31/1/2012')
```

should work. So what error you get when you run it?

EDIT:
Tried this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(m,CAST('1/31/2012' AS datetime))
```

and

```
SELECT DATEPART(m,CONVERT(datetime, '31/1/2012', 103))
```

Always gives me 1 as month as I expected.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't use the word error. The isdate is checking as mdy instead of dmy (if i don't use the set statement)

Comment: I tried this on german and windows based sql right now. works fine here. Do you get the same problem if you CAST() it before? Like SELECT IsDate(CAST('31/01/2012' As datetime)) ?

Comment: The following query results in mdy: Select DateFormat  
From   sys.syslanguages  
Where  name = @@Language

Comment: Just edited my post, you have to deal with CAST/CONVERT imho.